# Why can't I convert a 'string' to an 'int' inside an aggregate method?

Tags: c#, .net

Why doesn't this work? Really can't figure this out.
[image]

Comment: you are trying to assign the aggregated value to an output which is a string? what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: _output is not integer type

Comment: Could you post your question as code rather than an image? So maybe search crawlers can index it...

Answer (score 5):

The Aggregate function is defined as:

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func)
```

(documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx))

notice that you are using a `string[]` which is an `IEnumerable<string>` so, `TSource` will going to be a `string`

Therefore, the result of the aggregate function will be a `string`, meaning that the lambda function you use inside the `Aggregate` must return a `string`. In your case, `Convert.ToInt32` returns an `Int32`

It would be interesting to know why you are using aggregate. It doesn't feel like you know what the aggregate function does (you can refer to the link above) or you are not sure on what to do with the parameters provided to the function.

**EDIT: ORIGINAL SS OF CODE CHANGED**

So, to fix the "new issue":

**C#**

```
    var test = new []{"0", "0", "0"};
    var output = test.Aggregate((x, y) => $"{Convert.ToInt32(x) + Convert.ToInt32(y)}");
```

**EDIT2: RETURNING AN INT32 WITH THE SUM OF THE VALUES**

**C#**

```
    var test = new []{"1", "3", "2"};
    var output = test.Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t));
```

Comment: If he wants an int back, this doesn't answer the question. You are correct that because test is strings that it must aggregate back to strings. He just needs to do a conversion over 'test' so that it is a list of ints first.

Comment: "Therefore, the result of the aggregate function will be a string, meaning that the lambda function you use inside the Aggregate must return a string. In your case, Convert.ToInt32 returns an Int32"

That made everything make sense. I understand the error now, thanks!

Comment: No worries @CarsonthePowers. If you are happy with it, you can mark as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually The `.Aggregate()` method Applies an accumulator function over a sequence. Here in your case you are processing a List of strings, so you have to get the string through iterations. The method `.ToString()` will help you to do the conversion after the addition. As per the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, you have to do the following changes to make your code work

```
string _output = test.Aggregate((x,y) => (Convert.ToInt32(x) + Convert.ToInt32(y)).ToString());
```

Checkout the example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mpy9s2)

Comment: Just changed it, still giving me problems.

Comment: what is the compiler saysnow?

Comment: I don't find any similarities in the update and my post

Comment: This again doesn't answer the expect int output. Not sure how this helps? Also this will NEVER work. Aggregate must return a string since test is a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] test = {"0", "1", "2", "3"};
            int output = test.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
            Console.WriteLine(output);

        }
```

**Explanation:**

Aggregate function returns the same type of data that you invoke it on. So, if you invoke it on a **string type array** it will return you a **string**. But in your case you want it to be an **integer**. So, you need to convert the **string array** into an **integer array**. Then you can use the Aggregate function to return an **integer** value.

Comment: that's what I'd do except like ```var output = test.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y)```

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'd do that as well, but I made the type visible here rather than using 'var' because the type is very important here to demonstrate the solution of the issue :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas Oh! man I forgot to remove that while refactoring :p. That was really unnecessary. Thanks. Updating the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert int after sum.  As Aggregate function apply to each successive element.

```
var _output = test.Aggregate((x, y) => (Convert.ToInt32(x) + Convert.ToInt32(y)).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregate function must return the same type as what is put into aggregate. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx)

You feed in an `IEnumerable<string>` into that method, and thus it expects that as the output. You are converting to int return types which would return int from the aggregator I believe. Since the aggregate function expects a string output, you are probably not using the correct LINQ type?

I recommend .Select() to convert, then .Aggregate to add them together.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error is that there is no explicit convertor from string to int you need to use `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` for this convertion. Your problem is 
in `(int)x` and `(int)y` in addition to that the `Aggregate()` method doesn't return int in your case.